# Don't receive the last state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a custom hook called useMetrics which has 2 main functions:

- updateMetricsBy: modifies a local state which will be used to save data to the server
- saveMetrics: saves data to the server

The problem is saveMetrics receives an old metrics state value for some reason. That's why we can investigate that the first calling won't update anything on the server:

[console picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLem0.png)

Codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-browser-nynxp7?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current code, you have no choice but to view it as the previous state value. One function is to update the status and check the status through callback. This means that the state works asynchronously and is not rendered again. Therefore, you cannot see the updated value because it calls the value that has not been re-rendered.

Here's how you can correctly verify the updated values.

```js
const useMetrics = () => {
// ...
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("!!Saved [metrics]", metrics);
  },[metrics])
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I save it to the server debounced then? I need the hook to give API to save it to the server (and be called in a particular moment - in this case it's right after tasks were saved).
With `useEffect` it's impossible

Comment: I did something like this, but not sure it's the best solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-tree-w7yx2q?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You can call api in useEffect, or you can call api through a parameter that adds a new state value to the existing state value in the function that updates. @volodymyr_dos